# How to use "until now/so far" in the past tenses?

Tags: phrases, prepositions, tenses

I know that "until now" indicates that something changed.

> No messages have come until now. *Now the first message arrived.*

But what about using it in the past, for example in reported speech or just meaning in the past?

> It was not clear to me until now. *The whole sentence is meant to refer to past, e.g. describing what happened during my studies.*

> I did not know much about trigonometry. So far, I was only using algebra. *When I was young.*

Comment: Use *then* in place of *now*. "No messages had come **until then**"; "**Until then**, I was only using algebra."

Comment: Thanks, also can I start the sentence with Until then? Until then, I was using only A. (meaning that after that, I started using also B)

Comment: Yes, as the second example above does.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear - the second example uses "so far" so nothing changed in that situation. With "until now", it would mean that it changed.

Comment: "**Until then**, I was only using algebra."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to place an entire sentence in the past.

> It was not clear to me until now.
>   I did not know much about trigonometry. So far, I was only using algebra.

There are several ways to do this. Using the first example, in speech, many people use the simplest forms to speak, so

> It was not clear to me **until then**/that point...

But writing is a bit more formal, so I would take your main verb, was/be and look at the past tenses: you want the past, you want it to have been done/finished in the past, so you want to look at least at the past *pluperfect* of *be, third person, singular*):

> It **had** not **been** clear to me until *then* (or choose your pint in the past when it became clear: that moment, until I had finished the semester, whenever.)

Do the same to your second example:

> I did not know much about trigonometry. So far, I was only using algebra.

*I did not know much about trigonometry* is fine, it's all in the past. So change the second sentence.

So far, I was only using algebra. (This is a bit incorrect, because your words, so far, and *was using* indicates a continuous action, so *was* doesn't match it in tense.

Be, past participle: been; pluperfect: had been + using (continuous) =

So far, I had only been using algebra. (For style reasons, I would change *So far* to *Up to that point* or something like it.)

> I did not know much about trigonometry. Back then, I **had** only **been using** algebra.

Don't feel discouraged if you can't speak like that yet. Most conversations are informal, and it's all put in a simpler past.

> I didn't know much about trigonometry. Back then, I only knew Algebra/was only using.

Comment: Thank you for a great and detailed answer! English is my third language but I do my best to improve it as much as I can!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm very happy to help. And, if you upvote, that will be good for me, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Up until now I had not been able to fix this car."

"If you can't sing well then I'd suggest some singing lessons. Until then, please do not attend our choir."

On a personal note, I wouldn't use "so far" too much in the past. In fact, I would refrain from it.

"So far" is best used with Present Perfect Progressive:

"So far, the company has hired a few candidates for the job."

Or Present Perfect Continuous:

So far, they have not been able to hire any new candidates."

There are, of course, exceptions but those you would have to commit by memory.